# Getting a short day name

Tags: c#, datetime-format

I was wondering on how to write a method that will return me a string which will contain the short day name, example:

```
public static string GetShortDayName(DayOfWeek day)
```

now if i call:

```
string monday = GetShortDayName(DayOfWeek.Monday);
```

I will get back "mo" if culture is en, or "lu" if culture is at example it.

Comment: `mo` is not an abbreviation for monday in culture `en` - if anything is standard it would be `mon`.

Comment: Yes I know that, I would like to get a string indicating the day in a short form, by passing in the method a DayOfWeek as parameter for the desired day and getting a cultural sensitive string out.

Comment: @Jamiec I saw that a format string for a day is date.ToString("ddd") and it gives in case of Monday "mo". For me "mon" is also fine. The fact is how to structure the method?

Comment: instead of adding the answer in your question, accept the answer by marking it as accepted.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You can use [`DateTimeFormatInfo.AbbreviatedDayNames`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.abbreviateddaynames.aspx). For example:

```
string[] names = culture.DateTimeFormat.AbbreviatedDayNames;
string monday = names[(int) DayOfWeek.Monday];
```

Comment: Watch out though - that array thinks that Sunday is the first day of the week. ;)

Comment: @MatthewWatson does that matter when you're indexing it with the enumeration `DayOfWeek`?

Comment: @MaiOM: I've edited the original sample instead of adding an unnecessary (IMO) method version.

Comment: And do not forget that if you already have a date, all you need to do is to call myDate.ToString("ddd") to get its short day name...

Answer (score 21):

You can use "ddd" in in a [custom format string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings) to get the short day name. For example.

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("ddd");
```

As suggestby @Loudenvier in comments.

Answer (score 10):

The closest you can get is use a [custom date and time format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) - specifically `ddd`.

This will return an abbreviation - you can substring the result to get to 2 characters.

You will need to use a `DateTime` with a day corresponding to the day of week you wish.

Answer (score 5):

```
DateTimeFormatInfo.ShortestDayNames
```

Gets or sets a string array of the shortest unique abbreviated day names associated with the current DateTimeFormatInfo object.

Comment: shouldn't it be `DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.AbbreviatedDayNames` :D

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
CultureInfo english = new CultureInfo("en-US");
string sunday = (english.DateTimeFormat.DayNames[(int)DayOfWeek.Sunday]).Substring(0, 2);
```

Or:

```
dateTimeFormats = new CultureInfo("en-US").DateTimeFormat;
string sunday = (dateValue.ToString("dddd", dateTimeFormats)).Substring(0, 2);
```