# System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo returns the same format in all languages?

Tags: powershell

I'm newbie at Powershell and actually in all the Windows Development Environment.

With this function:

```
[System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo]::CurrentInfo.AbbreviatedDayNames[0]
```

I can have the abbreviation of the first day of the week of the user. So, for example, in my computer with local as Spanish-Mexico it returns

```
dom
```

The question I have is:

If I run that same snippet in all the world, will it gave me the same day? Sunday? Or it can gave me in some cases monday? The reason is I'm creating a script at powershell that will add tasks to the system, but since it will be used around the globe, I don't want it create the tasks for monday, instead of sunday...

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Your suspicions are correct -- the first day of the week in .NET is not always Sunday: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/global_developer/archive/2011/06/03/what-is-the-first-day-of-the-week-really.aspx It could also be Monday.  In fact, there are some cases where it is Saturday!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For safety AND readability, you can always do this:

```
[System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo]::CurrentInfo.AbbreviatedDayNames[[DayOfWeek]::Sunday]
```

Related: [Getting a short day name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12530116/getting-a-short-day-name)

Answer (score 1):

@manojlds is the right way to avoid problem with `FirstDayOfWeek` in different cultures.
Here just a way to find FDoW for all Cultures

```
[System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::GetCultures( "allcultures" ) |
select displayname, @{n="FirstDayWeek";e={ $_.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek }}
```

Comment: @AbrahamSustaita Yes.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It save me hours of experiments :)